# How fast is copying files using ruby - against cp command?

Tags: c, ruby, linux, cp

First, I know that when copying a file, if the **buffer size** is bigger, the copying process will be faster.

The following **ruby** script used to write line-by-line (i.e. size of buffer will depends on the line length):

```
input,output = ARGV[0], ARGV[1]

f_in = File.open input, "r"
f_out = File.open output, "w"

f_in.each {|line| f_out << line}

f_in.close
f_out.close
```

#### Ruby Script *VS* to Linux [cp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html)  command

I've tried to copy a two files of size (300, 400 MBs), and found the above script is even faster than the **cp** Linux command, notably faster.

How this could happen? I suppose the `cp` is fully optimized!

Comment: Which one did you run first? Could be your disk cache at work.

Comment: And further to Thilo's comment, you don't just run things once to benchmark them, you need to run thousands of iterations and flush caches to get worthwhile numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably due disk caches, try running

`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

to clear up the cache before running your benchmark :)

my guess is that they do should be very, very close, ofcourse cp should start copying some miliseconds faster than ruby.

Answer (score 3):

It probably is happening because of the file system disk cache inside the kernel.

I'm sure that if you repeat several times a `cp` command, timings will be different.

Use the `time` command (as a prefix) to benchmark and repeat the test several times.

Comment: I agree, the `cp` command is very faster in subsequent times.